# Bootstrap Carousel image shows two times in Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, bootstrap-4

I am new to development ,Here in my project I have a carousel currently I have 10 images (receiving image paths from databse through json response on page load).

What is my problem is ,The first image is showing two times .

app.component.ts

```
this.CartdataService.get_Basic_Images().subscribe(
      data => {

        this.get_Carousel_Images = data['1'];
        this.slider_Active_Item = data[1][0]['CAROUSEL_IMAGE_PATHS'];
      });
```

Here I have select the first image from the json response and set into the Active item.I want to set it automatic.

app.component.HTML

```
 <div class="col">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="col-sm-12  col-md-12 carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                    <div class="carousel-inner">
                        <div class="carousel-item active">
                            <img class="d-block w-100" src="{{slider_Active_Item}}" alt="First slide">
                        </div>
                        <div *ngFor="let sliders of get_Carousel_Images; let i = index" class="carousel-item">
                            <img class="d-block w-100" [src]="sliders['CAROUSEL_IMAGE_PATHS']" [alt]="'img' + i">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                    </a>
                    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
                        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

can anyone help me to fix it .

Comment: Can you provide a stackblitz of your issue? It would be easier to help you.

If you want to use bootstrap in angular app you can think about using https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/carousel . You will get access to bootstrap done in more angular way. There is no need of inventing the wheel again.

Comment: @AdrianSawicki https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bootstrap-carousel-dynamic2-prrges?file=app%2Fone%2Fone.component.html

Comment: @AdrianSawicki here I have given the stacklitz code there you can see the "first slide " comes two times ,I could not reproduce the carousel 100% ,Images paths are not working there

Comment: @AdrianSawicki did you checked it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to remove the first image from your images list. You can filter it out. You have a double first image because of:

```
 <div class="carousel-item active">
   <img class="d-block w-100" src="{{slider_Active_Item}}" alt="First slide">
 </div>
```

Here is the first active image and later on in loop you're using the same because it's not filtered out of the list of accessible images.

If you filter it out you will add every image without the first, which was already used.

```
this.get_Carousel_Images = data['1'].filter((img, i) => i !== 0);
```

[stackblitz...](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bootstrap-carousel-dynamic2-prrges)

Another option would be to just remove that image from the data list and give a direct link to your first active image. There isn't a need of selecting it from an array.